# Use of < or ≤ in big-O

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

I've seen two different formal definitions of O notation:

f(n) = O(g(n)) if there are constants n<sub>0</sub>, c where for any  n<sub>0</sub>, we have f(n) < cg(n)

And

f(n)  O(g(n)) if there are constants n<sub>0</sub>, c where for any <sub>0</sub>, we have f(n) ≤ cg(n)

The difference is whether f(n) is strictly less than cg(n) or less than or equal to cg(n).

Are these definitions equal? If so, how do I prove it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, not programming. use cs.stackexchange.com (where they will undoubtedly ask you what you've tried.)

Comment: Perhaps you've misstated the problem, eg left out some ∃ marks and a spec for f.  For the problem as stated, A and B need not be identical sets.  For example, with f(n)=n and c = n0 = 1 and g(n)=n-1 if n>1 else 3, we have g(n0) ≮ c·f(n0) so this g is in A but not in B

Comment: If you want to ask a different question about big-O, we'd recommend asking a separate question rather than editing this question to change the meaning. That way, if anyone wants to find this original question, they can do so.

Comment: Please stop editing this question to radically change what's being asked. If you want to ask something else, please ask it separately.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, if you have that

> f(n) < c g(n) for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>

then it is also the case that

> f(n) ≤ c g(n) for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>.

Similarly, suppose that

> f(n) ≤ c g(n) for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>

Supposing that g(n) ≥ 1, then you get, for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>, that

> f(n) ≤ c g(n) ≥ cg(n) + 1 ≤ c g(n) + g(n) = (c + 1)g(n)

Therefore, using the new constant c' = c + 1, we get

> f(n) < c' g(n) for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>

Hope this helps!